# Blank SMS from Kannel

Tags: php, linux, sms, kannel

I am sending an SMS from my web application in my laptop to a phone. The problem is that the SMS is always blank. Could anyone know what may be wrong. Below is the url I use to pass the variables to kannel(username,password and telephone number have been eXd for obvious reasons). I can receive the sms. But its always blank

```
http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=xxxxx&password=xxxxx&to=+254xxxxxxxxx&test=message
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your URL uses the key `test` where it should use `text`.

Try the following:

```
http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=xxxxx&password=xxxxx&to=+254xxxxxxxxx&text=message
```

Reference: [Kennel manual](http://www.kannel.org/download/kannel-userguide-snapshot/userguide.html#AEN4623)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need `text=message` rather than `test=message`